# Unable to find source java class when using latest gradle version 3.2.1

Tags: android, class, gradle

Previously, I was using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

and everything was working fine.

After upgrading to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

however, I see the following issue. after build the project using the command

`./gradlew assembleDebug`

After build success, I can not find `classes` or `app_classes` in `app/build/intermediates` but I need source `classes` files.

why it happend?

Comment: delete all subfolders in `build/` clean and build your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using gradle 4.6 add this to your `build.gradle` file

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

as for 3.2+ you will need gradle 4.6 atleast, check documentation here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

If your build is from debug and you have not build using `build -> build apk` then you can find the required classes in below path.

```
build\intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

Comment: first, thanks, in the                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and use the gradle url                                    
 `distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip`

Comment: try to delete all subfolders in build/ clean and build your project.

Comment: thanks again, every time, build by `./gradlew clean assembleDebug`

Comment: can you check that you have added `google()` to your project level gradle?

Comment: can you try to downgrade to version 4.6 in distribution url and check once.

Comment: yes, I had tried it ,it also can not found the source java classes

Comment: if your build is debug check here `build\intermediates\javac\debug\compileDebugJavaWithJavac`

Comment: yes, I find the dir `app/build/intermediates/javac/internalDebug/compileInternalDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/`